# Meteor.call removes all undefined properties between client and server

Tags: meteor, call

I have the following call:

`Meteor.call('updateDoc', id, obj);`

with updateDoc defined as:

```
Meteor.methods({
    updateDoc(id, doc) {
        MyCollection.update(id, {$set: doc});
    }
});
```

Calling it with obj being

```
{
    param1: undefined,
    param2: 'defined!'
}
```

results in doc received as

```
{
    param2: 'defined!'
}
```

meaning that somewhere between the call and the method trigger, Meteor "cleaned" out the undefined property.

I suspect they are using JSON.stringify along the way and that's why undefined is removed.

Aside for using null instead of undefined (which works), is there a way to force meteor to pass along undefined?

As a side note, updating a collection on client side also has the effect of "losing" undefined properties, i.e. doing this update on client side would actually only update param2, and ignore param1 so that if param1 had a previous value it would remain intact (as opposed to being unset as Mongo 2.4 onward does)

Comment: instead of undefined, if you do not want to use *null*, you can use empty strings *""*

Comment: can you post your insert method for us to see the document structure in DB? it will be easier to edit your code then

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `MyCollection.update(id, {$set: doc});` like this

```
MyCollection.update(id, {
  $set: {docYouWantToChange: doc}
});
```

Comment: not sure i understand what would go into docYouWantToChange